# Angularjs: Set a radio button to checked based on stored data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, radio-button

I'm trying to check the radio button of the account type. It's in the database correctly, but it doesn't show up with I load this page. However, when I click a radio button, it updates the value correctly and shows itself as checked.

The account.accountType is an enum with 3 choices internal = 0, customer = 1, or proposal = 2. 
It can also be null before it's been set and then nothing would be checked.
How do I do this?

I'm on angular 1.4.9 and using typescript for the controller.

```html
<div class="form-group" 
ng-class="{ 'has-error': accountForm.$submitted && accountForm.accountType.$invalid }">
          <label for="customerName">Account type:</label>
             <div>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                   <input type="radio" name="accountType" 
                   id="internal" value="0" ng-model="account.accountType" 
                   ng-required="true" ng-checked="account.accountType == 0"> Internal
                </label>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                   <input type="radio" name="accountType" 
                   id="customer" value="1" ng-model="account.accountType" 
                   ng-required="true" ng-checked="account.accountType == 1"> Customer
                </label>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                   <input type="radio" name="accountType" id="proposal" 
                   value="2" ng-model="account.accountType" ng-required="true" 
                   ng-checked="account.accountType == 2"> Proposal
                </label>
             </div>
<p class="text-danger" ng-if="accountForm.$submitted && accountForm.accountType.$invalid">Please choose an account type</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Post your controller code to understand better.

Answer (score 0):

//`change value of account.accountType in your controller then the corresponding //checkBox will be checked.
//for example, i have set account.accountType as 2 with ng-init then 
//secondcheckbox will be checked on load`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="" ng-init="account.accountType = 2" class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': accountForm.$submitted && accountForm.accountType.$invalid }">
  <label for="customerName">Account type:</label>{{account.accountType}}
  <div>
    <label class="radio-inline">
                   <input type="radio" name="accountType" 
                   id="internal" value="1" ng-model="account.accountType" 
                   ng-required="true" ng-checked="account.accountType == 1"> Internal
                </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
                   <input type="radio" name="accountType" 
                   id="customer" value="2" ng-model="account.accountType" 
                   ng-required="true" ng-checked="account.accountType == 2"> Customer
                </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
                   <input type="radio" name="accountType" id="proposal" 
                   value="3" ng-model="account.accountType" ng-required="true" 
                   ng-checked="account.accountType == 3"> Proposal
                </label>
  </div>
  <p class="text-danger" ng-if="accountForm.$submitted && accountForm.accountType.$invalid">Please choose an account type</p>
</div>
```

Comment: account.accountType is actually an enum. So this solution didn't work for me. I edited the question. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

ng-checked directive should not be used together with ngModel, as this can lead to unexpected behavior.
use this for each radio

```
  <input type="radio" name="accountType"
                   id="internal" value="0"
                   ng-required="true" ng-checked="account.accountType == 0">
```

Comment: account.accountType is actually an enum. So this solution didn't work for me. I edited the question. Sorry.